# k8s access denied when pulling local images

Tags: kubernetes, podman

I use podman with a local registry. I am able to pull the images from the command line and also see the manifest. When I deploy my k8s it fails to pull the image with error access denied. Any idea's? I Googled for days now but do not get an answer that works.

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on VMWARE if that maybe makes a difference. Thank you.

kubelet            Failed to pull image "localhost:5001/datawire/aes:3.1.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "localhost:5001/datawire/aes:3.1.0": failed to resolve reference "localhost:5001/datawire/aes:3.1.0": failed to do request: Head "http://localhost:5001/v2/datawire/aes/manifests/3.1.0": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5001: connect: connection refused

Comment: The host/vm kubernetes is running probably doesn't have the registry on too. It is trying to connect to localhost (which may not be a physical machine) on port 5001. Check that your registry is listening there and is not firewalled or change the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When Kubernetes attempts to create a new pod but is unable to pull the required container image, an error message stating "**Failed to pull image**" will be displayed. When you try to add a new resource to your cluster with a command like "`kubectl apply`," you should see this right away. When you inspect the pod with "`kubectl describe pod/my-pod`," the error will appear in the Events.

Pull errors are caused by the nodes in your cluster. Each node's Kubelet worker process is in charge of obtaining the images required to process a pod scheduling request. When a node is unable to download an image, the status is reported to the cluster control plane.

Images may not pull for a variety of reasons. It's possible that your nodes' networking failed, or that the cluster as a whole is experiencing connectivity issues. If you are online, the registry is up, and pull errors continue to occur, your firewall or traffic filtering may be malfunctioning.

Refer this [doc1](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-error-codes-failed-to-pull-image) and [doc2](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff) for more information.